# Pyinstaller subprocess exception When running on windowed mode

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller to create my application.In my django app, I'm using subprocess. When i execute pyinstaller in `noconsole` mode its throwing errors.
Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
  File "site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
  File "crumbs_tableau\views.py", line 1603, in parser
  File "site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
  File "site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 96, in render_to_string
  File "site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 43, in get_template
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: helpers/error.html
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crumbs_tableau\views.py", line 286, in parser
  File "crumbs_tableau\views.py", line 248, in mac_list
  File "subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 403, in run
  File "subprocess.py", line 667, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 905, in _get_handles
  File "subprocess.py", line 955, in _make_inheritable
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
  File "site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
  File "crumbs_tableau\views.py", line 1603, in parser
  File "site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
  File "site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 96, in render_to_string
  File "site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 43, in get_template
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: helpers/error.html
Not Found: /static/parser/bootstrap.css.map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define stdin and stderr when calling a subprocess in windowed mode.
Example:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["netstat", "-a", "-n", "-o"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

This is because windows tries to duplicate these handles if they're not set to null.